# how to check if a file is contained in another file, ignoring whitespace changes

Tags: css, file, compression, minify

Suppose I have some css files (a.css, b.css, ..., e.css) such that if you concatenate and compress all the css files, you generate another css file (compressed.css). I want to now check that each of the original css files is present in the compressed.css file. Are are there any tools in unix or somewhere else that can check if some files are contained in another file, ignoring whitespace changes?

Comment: Why don't you just concatenate the original files again and simply compare that with the output of the compressor?  E.g. cat f1 f2 f3 f4 | cmp - uncompressedoutput.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any tools to do exactly what you need out of the box. You'll need to write your own script -or program- to do this for you. You could use one of the many options in [diff](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/udiff.htm) to come up with a script that does what you need.